# I got a problem with this (htmlspecialchars)

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\inventarisrf\update.php on line 34

Data Gagal diupdate.";

        }

    }

    ?>

Comment: You should not add picture with code but just code. .. Also what is wrong? Notice has nothing to do with htmlspecialchars

Comment: Seems the variable is not set. Before doing anything check if it has been set using `if(isset($_POST['id']))`

Comment: I posted a code

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$id=null;` before you declare `$id`

example:

```
$id=null;
$id= htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
```